# SQL extracting date substring using regexp_subtr

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I've got a field named signal_notes containing strings like the follow (this would be a single value of signal_notes):

```
"{ ^search_date^: ^2021-01-05^, 
^filing_date^: ^^, 
^expiry_date^: ^^, 
^other_liens^: ^^, 
^who_1st_positon^: ^^, 
^who_2nd_position^: ^^, 
^who_3rd_position^: ^^, 
^priority_from_1^: ^^, 
^priority_from_2^: ^^, 
^priority_from_3^: ^^, 
^notes^: ^^ 
^client_facing_notes^: ^^ 
 }"
```

Sometimes, the *^expiry_date^* line will have a date between the ^'s in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

My new field *expiry_date* will ideally be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' with the date string from the *signal_notes* field.

This is what I've got so far, but it returns nothing.

```
select
(regexp_substr(signal_notes, 'expiry_date [0-9-]*' )) as expiry_date
from db
```

Ive also tried

```
(regexp_substr( signal_notes, '^expiry_date^: ^[0-9-]*^' )) as first_as_of_date_context
```

with the same results.

Any advice welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a subexpression.  The `^` is a pain, one way around that is:

```
regexp_substr(signal_notes, '.expiry_date.: .([0-9-]*).', 1, 1, 'e')
```

This is very similar to your last attempt, except it has the subexpression so it should only return the date.

You should also be able to use `\\` as an escape character:

```
regexp_substr(signal_notes, '\\^expiry_date\\^: \\^([0-9-]*)\\^', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Comment: I tried this but returns nulls just like my previous attempts

Comment: @CaguamaRodrigez . . . There must be some other issue . . . perhaps multiple spaces or look-alike characters.

Comment: My initial guess was that the '^' characters were causing problems as they are parameters used in regexp_substr. There aren't any spaces or look-alikes unfortunately.

Comment: @CaguamaRodrigez . . . Duh.  Good observation.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Getting the following error:
ERROR: Found a closing ) with no corresponding openening parenthesis. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^]([0-9-]*>>>HERE>>>)[^]'.

Everything seems fine to me though?

Also tried replacing the square brackets with (), but returned nulls.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the '.'s work?

Comment: @CaguamaRodrigez . . . They match any character.  Kind of cheating, but simple.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a ton for the help. If you referenced a specific source and still have it available, I would love to take a look.